# setting environment variable in different folder in python

Tags: python

I'm in folder A & need to programatically set environment variable ENV_VAR in Folder B/C

I'm doing this right now

```
command = "cd B/C; export ENV_VAR=/Folder1/Folder2; "
fip = open('NUL','wb+')
subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = fip, stderr =fip, shell=True)
```

I'm getting the following error 
/bin/sh:: ENV_VAR=/Folder1/Folder2  is not an identifier

UPDATE: I guess I just want to know how to set environment variables in python such that it's visible to processes residing in different folders. I always though environment variables once set, can be seen from anywhere. But I am on solaris and that doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense in the first place. Environment variables don't apply to directories, they apply to processes. If you got this to work, all it would mean is that all child processes of the shell—that is, no processes at all—see the env variable. Also, on what platform is devnull called `NUL` like on Windows, but the shell supports `export` like on `bash`?

Comment: At any rate, this seems like a paradigm [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Maybe if you explain what you're actually trying to accomplish by "setting an environment variable in a different folder" someone can tell you what you actually want to do.

Comment: I want to export an environment variable. From folder A, I am initiating a process which resides in B/C. I was setting the environment variable using os.environ['ENV_VAR']="XYZ" but the process in B/C doesn't see this environment variable. I guess I just need a way to export environment variable programatically so that process from all the folder see it.

Comment: abarnert - I am on solaris.

Comment: If you're on Solaris, then `NUL` is just a regular file named `NUL` in whatever the current working directory happens to be, which doesn't seem very useful. Most likely you wanted `/dev/null` there, but copied someone's Windows code? Or, better, `os.devnull`. Or, even better (if you're on 3.3+) don't bother opening a file, just pass `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL` and let Python take care of it.

Comment: As for your update… that's just such a misapprehension of what environment variables do and how they work that I don't think anyone can answer it without writing a tutorial. So really, you need a basic tutorial on Unix, shell scripts, and/or bash.

Comment: I can give you some hints to get you started: environment variables care nothing about directories; a process can pass any environment it wants to any children it launches, but by default it passes them a copy of its own. So, environment variables are generally visible to any of your own children (no matter what directory they're in), and never visible to anyone else. I don't think that explains how to do what you want at all, but it may explain why what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

`/bin/sh` is not required to support all the features that you're probably used to from `bash`

Use `ENV_VAR=/foo; export ENV_VAR`, or else use `command = ['bash', '-c', command]` and `shell=False`

Comment: This almost certainly explains the problem he's directly asking about. It probably won't do what he's hoping it will, but then I'm having a hard time imagining what he's hoping it will do in the first place, so that's not a problem with your answer…